# Fabric.js dynamic text with variable

Tags: javascript, text, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want some text on an image. This works fine, but i also want that the text comes dynamically from a mysql db.

Now i need a variable to insert into the object.

```
var myVariable = "text";

var text = new fabric.Text(myVariable, {
              fontFamily: 'Comic Sans',
              fontSize: 20
            });
```

I don't get it solved by:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('picture.png', function(img) {

        img.setWidth(100);
        img.setHeight(50);

        theNumber = "2";
```

//or

```
theNumber = 2;


        var text = new fabric.Text(theNumber2, {
          fontFamily: 'Comic Sans',
          fontSize: 20
        });


        text.set({ text: theNumber2 });
```

I get in the console, 
Uncaught TypeError: this.text.split is not a function fabric.min.js:7

Can i add the text in another way dynamically?

Comment: your code is working fine. If you want to add text dynamically you can do it with the help of api.

Comment: You are right, code is working fine with strings. No clue why it wasn't working in the first place. Tanky you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var theNumber = 2;
var text = new fabric.Text(theNumber.toString(), {
  fontFamily: 'Comic Sans',
  fontSize: 20,
  left:50,
  top:50
});

canvas.add(text);

//image with text(Number)

fabric.Image.fromURL('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9b/Yoda_Empire_Strikes_Back.png', function(img) {

    img.setWidth(100);
    img.setHeight(100);

    var text = new fabric.Text(theNumber.toString(), {
      fontFamily: 'Comic Sans',
      fontSize: 20,
      fill:'white',
      left:img.width/2,
      top:img.height/2,
      originX:'center',
      originY:'center',
    });
    var group = new fabric.Group([img, text]);
    canvas.add(group);
    canvas.centerObject(group);
    group.setCoords();
  });
//text.set({ text: theNumber2 });
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Use like this `theNumber.toString()` , because you are setting a number , make it as string then set it to fabric.Text.